# Show Addon Panel in Sequencer only, not Image Preview

Tags: python, add-on, video-sequence-editor

I want [Bligify](https://github.com/doakey3/Bligify)'s user interface to only appear on the right side of the sequencer in the Video Sequence Editor. Currently it appears in the preview window as well.

It would also be nice if it only appeared in the "Strip" section of the sequencer, not "Modifiers".

The addon's UI is defined like this:

```
class gif_UI(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_space_type = "SEQUENCE_EDITOR"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_label = "Bligify"
```

I suspect I need to add a line about [bl_context](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.Panel.html?highlight=bl_context#bpy.types.Panel.bl_context), but documentation has not been updated on this.

Bligify shows up in blender like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `bl_category` to the tab name you want to use. For example, `bl_category = 'Strip'`. You can use a new name too, to create a new tab.

To only show your panel in the sequencer and sequencer+preview modes, and not the preview mode, add this to your panel class:

```
@classmethod
def poll(cls, context):
    return context.space_data.view_type in {'SEQUENCER', 'SEQUENCER_PREVIEW'}
```

If you want to have it only in sequencer mode, you can change it to:

```
@classmethod
def poll(cls, context):
    return context.space_data.view_type == 'SEQUENCER'
```

PS: I found this bit of code by inspecting the sources of a built-in Blender panel that appears in the sequencer mode and not the preview mode. Just right-click and choose "Edit Source".

Comment: Thanks! This is the answer to part of my question. I'd still like to prevent the addon from appearing in the Image Preview area if possible.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include that too.